Expectation of rectified normal distribution
In this post, it is stated that, for $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, we have that \begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\max(X,0)] &= \mu \left(1-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right) + \sigma \phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)
\end{align}
Then for $\mu = 0$, this simplifies to $\mathbb{E}[\max(X,0)] = \sigma \phi\left(0\right) = \sigma \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.
However, if we consider the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} x\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$$ we get $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, so we have a factor of $\sigma$ that was lost before. Could someone help me reconcile the two approaches? Pretty sure they should be equal, since $\max(X,0)=X\mathbf{1}_{X > 0}$. Thanks a lot.

$\phi (0)$ is $\frac 1  {\sqrt {2\pi}}$, not $\frac 1  {\sigma \sqrt {2\pi}}$

Hm? We have that $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x/\sigma)^2}$

$\phi$ and $\Phi$ stand for CDF and pdf of standard normal distribution, not CDF and pdf of $X$.
